# How to Develop Reports in Birt and using in ASP.NET?

Tags: java, asp.net, report, birt

I am tottaly a new bie in Reporting. My problem is , I need to use Birt for reporting in ASP.NET . But seems that Birt is only available in Java. I don't know how to use it in ASP.NET . I don't want to use Crystal reports as Its not free.

I also observe that designing reports in Birt also not free via Actuate API. So,any body having any idea about the usage of Birt for developing,designing and viewing reports in ASP.NET

I want the functionality like ( Avg, Sums, Complex Formulas Work , and generic features of any reporting tool ) in order to  view the data over Web using ASP.NET via Birt Reports.

Comment: If you are using asp.net with a SQLServer database, have you considered using SQLServer Reporting Services?

Comment: Yes, Sure I am using ASP.NET with SQLServerExpress of MSFT. But didn't used any reporting so far..As , I have to deploy some project and need to use Free Reporting that gives all rich features as I discussed above. I think Crystal Reports are rich but might be they are not free..
And yes I didn't used SQLServer Reporting ..What should then I use?

Comment: SSRS would definitely be worth a look - it comes free with SQLServer and has similar features to Crystal, plus the Designer environment has more in common with BIRT than with Crystal's "banded" designer approach.

Comment: Having used SSRS, I would not recommend it versus BIRT. It's expensive (in $ and system resources) and forever ties you to SQL Server.  It's also a pain to set up and configure properly.

Answer (score 6):

If you can install Java on your server alongside .NET, you can just run the BIRT server on localhost and proxy to it from .NET.   Here's a (partial) sample from an MVC controller:

```
     private FileResult PdfTest(string reportPath, List<ReportParameter> parameters)
     {
        string url = "http://localhost:8080/birt/frameset?__report=test.rptdesign&sample=" + reportPath + "&__dpi=96&__format=pdf&__pageoverflow=0&__asattachment=true&__overwrite=false";
        url += urlParams;
        using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            return File(wc.DownloadData(url), "application/pdf");
        }
    }
```